# Таблица из БД id после выбора отправить в переменную, чтобы потом присвоить другому элементу, как это сделать?

Tags: php, html, input

Вот тут код предоставил ниже.
Циклом создаю таблицу на странице, после нажатия на кнопку отправить в глобальную переменную не могу получить ID выбранной строки. Как же это сделать?

```html
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
    $page = $_GET['pageno'];}
    else {$page=1;}
    $notesOnPage = 12;
    $from = ($page - 1) * $notesOnPage;
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `id_p`,`id_prod`,`name_p`,`sum_p`,`code_p`,`brend_p` FROM `products` WHERE `id_c`={$_COOKIE['id_k']} AND id_p>0 LIMIT $from, $notesOnPage");
      while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        echo '<tr>' .
             "<td>{$result['id_p']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['name_p']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['sum_p']} сум</td>" .
             "<td><input type='file' name='images[]' multiple></td>" .
             "<td><input type='submit' value=\"Отправить\"></td>" .
             '</tr>';
      }
 ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Alisher Ahmedov, в вашем вопросе недостаточно информации. Укажите место, где вы сохраняете id в глобальную переменную. Укажите также, как вы ее получаете с формы.
Например,

```
setcookie('id', $_GET['id']);
```

Чтобы получить данные id методом GET HTTP, вы можете формировать таблицу следующим образом:

```
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            echo '<tr>' .
                 "<td>{$result['id_p']}</td>" .
                 "<input type='hidden' value='{$result['id_p']}' name='id'>".
                 "<td>{$result['name_p']}</td>" .
                 "<td>{$result['sum_p']} сум</td>" .
                 "<td><input type='file' name='images[]' multiple></td>" .
                 "<td><input type='submit' value=\"Отправить\"></td>" .
                 '</tr>';
          }
```

Comment: Привет, вот так считает все id и выводит последний, а мне нужен id текущей строки, когда жму кнопку отправить. А вот как получить id - это основной вопрос моей темы.

Answer (score 0):

Тут ещё изменил и получил переменную, но эту же переменную почему-то не получается дописать в имя файла в загруженном файле.

```html
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        echo '<tr>' .
             "<td>{$result['id_p']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['name_p']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['sum_p']} сум</td>" .
             "<td><input type='file' name='images[]' multiple></td>" .
             "<td><a href='?ids={$result['id_p']}#third'> Отправить </td>" .
             '</tr>';
      }
```

Вот тут код для загрузки файла, по не загружает даже сам файл. Может с проверками переборщил. Код конечно взял с ресурса интернета не помню где именно.

```html
<?php
// Если в $_FILES существует "image" и она не NULL
if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
  $image = $_FILES['image'];
  // Получаем нужные элементы массива "image"
  $fileTmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $errorCode = $_FILES['image']['error'];
  // Проверим на ошибки
  if ($errorCode !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK || !is_uploaded_file($fileTmpName)) {
    // Массив с названиями ошибок
    $errorMessages = [
      UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE => 'Размер файла превысил значение upload_max_filesize в конфигурации PHP.',
      UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE => 'Размер загружаемого файла превысил значение MAX_FILE_SIZE в HTML-форме.',
      UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL => 'Загружаемый файл был получен только частично.',
      UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE => 'Файл не был загружен.',
      UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => 'Отсутствует временная папка.',
      UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => 'Не удалось записать файл на диск.',
      UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION => 'PHP-расширение остановило загрузку файла.',0
    ];
    // Зададим неизвестную ошибку
    $unknownMessage = 'При загрузке файла произошла неизвестная ошибка.';
    // Если в массиве нет кода ошибки, скажем, что ошибка неизвестна
    $outputMessage = isset($errorMessages[$errorCode]) ? $errorMessages[$errorCode] : $unknownMessage;
    // Выведем название ошибки
    die($outputMessage);
  }
  else {
    echo 'Ошибок нет.';
    $nnn = $_COOKIE['login'];
    $path = "files/S-$nnn";
    foreach ($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
      if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $path . $_GET['ids'] . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$name");
      }
    }  
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        echo '<tr>' .
             "<td>{$result['id_p']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['name_p']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['sum_p']} сум</td>" .
             "<td><a href='blocks/third_form.php?ids={$result['id_p']}' target=\"_blank\" onclick=\"window.open('blocks/third_form.php','Жми...','resizable=yes,width=550,height=350,left=500,top='+(screen.availHeight/2-365)+'');return false;\">Жми...</a></td>" .
             '</tr>';
        }
```

Вот тут реализовал всплывающий окно отдельно на другом браузере. Но, также не могу передать переменную из таблицы. Вот так href='blocks/third_form.php?ids={$result['id_p']}', где ошибка?

Ошибка найдена, вот так переделал:
"<a href='blocks/third_form.php' target="_blank" onclick="window.open('blocks/third_form.php?ids={$result['id_p']}&name={$result['name_p']}&sum={$result['sum_p']}','Жми...','resizable=yes,width=550,height=350,left=500,top='+(screen.availHeight/2-365)+'');return false;">Жми..." .

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).